# Calling PHP webservice from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-events

I am new to PHP and JavaScript development, I am trying to execute this code but it fails:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])) {

 // do logic for logining in (usually query your db)
if ($_POST['username'] == 'test' && $_POST['password'] == 'test') {
$data['success'] = true;
$data['message'] = 'Login succesful';
} else {
$data['success'] = false;
$data['message'] = 'Login failed';
}
// return json
echo json_encode($data);

}
?>
```

Here is the JavaScript file:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    alert("dddd");
        $('#loginForm').submit(function() {
            $('#output').html('Connecting....');
            var postTo = 'http://localhost/Login/login.php';
            alert(postTo);
            $.post(postTo,{username: $('[name=username]').val() ,   password: $('[name=password]').val()} , 
                function(data) {
                
                    if(data.message) {
                        alert(data);
                    } else {
                        $('#output').html('Could not connect');
                    }
                
                },'json');
            
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you please provide more information on how it fails?  Do you get a javascript error?  Does data.message ever get alerted?

Comment: it displays the  Connecting.... string , and does not alert (data.message).

Comment: But when i put a $('#output').html('Connecting....'); after $.post , it gets executed

Comment: will it be error if i dont define $data ? , i tried by removing all the if conditions and just the $data['success'] = true;
$data['message'] = 'Login succesful';, and it displayed the created JSON in the browser, that is when i tried only from the browser

Comment: @user1284732, Yes, that's probably the problem. You can't use a variable without defining it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funnily enough it works for me in Firefox. I had the problem with IE a while back and the solution was to add the correct headers to the top of the php script:

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
...
```

**EDIT:** Reproduced it by calling it from another machine. try to change `var postTo = 'http://localhost/test/test.php';` to `var postTo = 'test/test.php';` .

here's what I tested with ( I woud recommend you use firebug and console.log() instead of alert()):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#output').html('somestuff');

    $('#loginForm').submit(function() {
        $('#output').html('Connecting....');
        var postTo = 'http://localhost/test/test.php';
        //alert(postTo);
        $.post(postTo,{username: $('[name=username]').val() ,   password:  $('[name=password]').val()} , 
            function(data) {

                if(data.message) {
                   //  console.log(data);
                    $('#output').html('Ya got it: '+ data.message);
                } else {
                    $('#output').html('Could not connect');
                }

            },'json');

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="loginForm">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="test"/>
    <input type="text" name="password" value="test"/>
    <input type="submit"  />
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$data` wasn't defined anywhere, this should fix it:

```
<?php
    $data = Array();
    if(isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])) {

         // do logic for logining in (usually query your db)
        if ($_POST['username'] == 'test' && $_POST['password'] == 'test') {
        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['message'] = 'Login succesful';
    } else {
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['message'] = 'Login failed';
    }
    // return json
    echo json_encode($data);

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])) {
```

should be

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
```

as a first correction.

Comment: Pretty sure that's not true. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: @user1284732, Yes, apparently the only difference is their operator precedence. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: @Walkerneo - Using "and" instead of "&&" simply means that if the first test fails, the second one will not be tested.  This code works for the required purpose.

Comment: @Eli, The page here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php says that all four operators `||`, `&&`, `and`, and `or` are short-circuit and that the difference is in their logical precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Install  Firefox with Firebug extension,  Open it using F12, Enable the 'NET', 'SCRIPT' and 'CONSOLE' tabs.  Put a breakpoint in the script (around the alert(postTo)) using the SCRIPT tab.  Refresh the page and step through it, monitoring the console.  Use the NET tab to check that both the request and response of the php script is correct.

The code above works in my environment, (with the slight change of alert(data) to alert(data.message)). The following works for me:

login.php:

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])) {
// do logic for logining in (usually query your db)
if ($_POST['username'] == 'test' && $_POST['password'] == 'test') {
$data['success'] = true;
$data['message'] = 'Login succesful';
} else {
$data['success'] = false;
$data['message'] = 'Login failed';
}
// return json
echo json_encode($data);

}
?>
```

login.html:

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jq/jquery.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("dddd");
        $('#loginForm').submit(function() {
            $('#output').html('Connecting....');
            var postTo = 'http://localhost/login.php';
            alert(postTo);
            $.post(postTo,{username: $('[name=username]').val() ,   password: $('[name=password]').val()} , 
                function(data) {

                    if(data.message) {
                        alert(data.message);
                    } else {
                        $('#output').html('Could not connect');
                    }

                },'json');

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id='loginForm'>
  <input type='text' id='username' name='username'/>
  <input type='text' id='password' name='password'/>
  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
```